# deformation retract and strong deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to gain some intuition about retracts, deformation retracts and strong deformation retracts (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract for definitions).
We have that any strong deformation retract is a deformation retract and any deformation retract is a retract (of course, by definition). Also, it is easy to think in a retract which is not a deformation retract.

Which are some examples of deformation retracts which are not strong deformation retracts?

Comment: See exercise 6 on page 18 of [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html). Note the difference in terminology to Wikipedia!

Comment: Similar question to this one has been asked again and an answer can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281564/natural-examples-of-deformation-retracts-that-are-not-strong-deformation-retract). The same example but with more details can be found [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/math432/Solution_1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Take the closed unit ball In the complex plane. For time $t=0$ apply the identity map. For $t \in (0,1/2]$ apply the map $e^{t i \pi} z$. For $t \in (1/2, 1]$ contract the ball to a point, $p$, other than the center. Since for $t$ equal to say $1/3$ the image of $p$ is not $p$ this map is not a strong deformation retraction, but meets the requirements for a deformation retraction.